# Binding to ComboBox SelectedValue when not using ItemSource

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I am having an issue where I have a ComboBox that I want to use to set an Enum to one of a few values from the Enum.

I expected I would be able to do so like below.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Tag" SelectedValue="{Binding ParameterType}">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Tag="{x:Static model:ParameterType.AbsMachine}">
        <TextBlock Text="M" ToolTip="Relative to the machine zero" />
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static model:ParameterType.AbsSample}">
        <TextBlock Text="S" ToolTip="Relative to sample zero"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="{x:Static model:ParameterType.RelCurrent}">
        <TextBlock Text="R" ToolTip="Relative to current value"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

However this doesnt appear to work and using snoop I can see that changing the combobox sets the local value removing the binding from SelectedValue.

If I instead do almost the same thing but setup a dummy collection that I bind itemsource to everything works as expected.

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding EndTypes, ElementName=RootControl}" SelectedValue="{Binding ParameterType}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ParameterTypeWrapper">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding ToolTip}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

I don't really understand why the approach with comboitems defined in XAML doesnt work as it appears a much neater solution for this case and doesn't pollute the code behind with additional wrapper classes and lists.

Does anybody know why binding to SelectedValue doesn't work unless an ItemsSource is used.

Comment: Read https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/ and/or https://brianlagunas.com/localize-enum-descriptions-in-wpf/

Comment: I have seen those kinds of solutions but they don't really answer the question on why one method works and the other breaks the binding.

Comment: I know that - otherwise I had posted it as an answer ;o)

Comment: What you are showing here just works. There might be something wrong in the code parts you haven't shown.

Comment: @Clemens just confirming both of these work for you, if I swap between the two chunks of XAML top one wipes the binding and bottom one works as expected. Not sure what other external factors could be at work.

Comment: No idea what's going on. I tried the first version and it works fine for me. And there is of course nothing obviously wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use SelectedItem instead. If you don't use ItemsSource it will be the selected ComboBoxItem.

So,

```
    <ComboBox SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
      var result = ((ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem).Tag;
    }
```

Not sure if you can use binding here.